# Touch issue with MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, touch, mpmovieplayer

I have very strange issue with MPMoviePlayer I have spent 2 days still not able to find the solution. I have just added view of MPMoviePlayer as a subview to self.view, but its not respond to touch methods. But when I remove MPMoviePlayer than view respond to touch method. I want to touch event with MPMoviePlayer.

Please help...

Comment: You can add tap gesture in MPMoviePlayer.

Comment: I don't want to use , because I have other function do to on touch method.

Comment: But you can give tag to tap gesture .so you can filter what to do when touch happened..

Comment: on touch event I want to increase and decrease volume

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below Seema

//Add tap gesture in movieplayer view...

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

//this method will be called when you touch on MPMovieplayer

```
 - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
 {
    // Your stuff to increase or decrease the volume.
 }
```

Let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: I am using MPMoviePlayer in my controller, if I remove MPMoviePlayer from view touches method works, after adding MPMoviePlayer in view touches method only works on MPMoviePlayer, MPMoviePlayer frame is (0,44,320,200), other area of view does not respond to touches method.

Comment: You can respond touch on other area by writing -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method.

Answer (score 0):

Check userInteractionEnabled on all views and check how you want get touches. If you use UIGestureRecognizer try add recognizer to MPMoviePlayer view when add it how subview.

Comment: userInteraction is enable for all views.